# Calculate each row values python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to calculate average of each row and result them in another new column at the each of the DataFrame. [This is small sample of data that I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNIZY.png)
I am not sure how I should write a function that can calculate row by row for it since my actual data will have something like 600K rows.

Comment: What kind of dataframe are you using? (Pandas / pyspark /...). Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: If this is `pandas`, you are looking for `df.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @JGC I am using Pandas and this is the code that I have used:

Comment: I got them now with df.mean(axis=1). Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,4]],columns=['B','A'],index=[1,2,3,4])
 df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
 df
 Output: 
    B  A  mean
 1  2  1   1.5
 2  3  2   2.5
 3  4  3   3.5
 4  5  4   4.5
```